# The output only one number in if statment

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, packet

It is a beginner's question, how come the output is only number 1 in this code.
is it supposed to be all numbers?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, []]
for number in a :
   if number == True:
      print(number)
```

I expected to be:

```
1
2
3
```

but it only get:

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
if number:
```

That will cover all non-zero numbers (and other objects) as they are "truthy" as in `bool(number) == True`.

If you compare `number == True`, you only get `1` since `1 == True` but not `2 == True`.

Note that `bool` is a subclass of `int` with `0 == False` and `1 == True`.

Comment: Thnx Sir for the feedback . it satisfies my question indeed.